# pass query string from sharepoint page to powerapps form

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms

Is there a way to pass dynamic parameter from SharePoint online site pages to Powerapps canvas app forms?

I am able to get the query string using Params function when I open the Canvas app directly in URL

However, I am looking for a way to pass the query string from SharePoint online page to Canvas App when I embed that in a page

Comment: Check [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/powerapps-app-on-sharepoint-modern-page-with-query-string-param) and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

To do that follow the below steps:

**Step 1:**

1. Embed the PowerApps form inside the SharePoint online page using the embed web part.
2. The Power Apps Embedded Inside  Tag On A Page. Now We Have Two Different Modern Pages Each Having Power App Forms.

**Step 2:  How to Pass the dynamic parameters?**

```
Pass The Parameter On Click On Any Item From One Page To Another Using Navigate Function.
Navigate(ScreenToNavigate, ScreenTransition.Fade, { Argument1: 04 , Argument2: SomeText })
In Another Page You Need To Collect/Catch This Parameter Value, You Can Get That By Different Functions,
Param(“ParamName”) Functions Or By Direct Assigning Values.
LookUp('***** Slips', 'Case Title'.Value = Param("[ParamName]"))
Filter('Case ****’,CaseTitle.Value=SelectParamName.SelectedText.Value)
```

**Note - Limitation**

In the above approach, the problem Is In Another Screen/Page Parameter Value Cannot Be Read As The Forms Are Embedded In Iframe. This Has Been Raised In **Microsoft Support And MS Had Considered this as limitation**.

**How to overcome the above challenge or what is the alternate approach?**

The Solution In This Scenario Is To Create Multiple Screens In The Same Power App Form And Then Embed
this Form In SharePoint Modern Page. Above Functions Remain Same But Now As There Is No **Iframe** It
Reads The Parameter And Get The Correct Value.

For more details refer to the below article:

[SHAREPOINT – PASSING PARAMETERS IN POWER APPS](https://theblueflamelabs.com/sharepoint-passing-parameters-in-power-apps/)